# Add something to a non-empty list in Scala

Tags: scala

I have this:

```
private val vertexIdListPartitions: TrieMap[Long, List[Long]] = TrieMap.empty[Long,List[Long]]
```

and i need to add something to the list of vertexIdListPartitions

if i write:

```
vertexIdListPartition.update(3,List(4,3))
```

I overwrite what was in the list before

if the list already has something inside, how can I link this new list? or still add numbers to the list?

How do i concat what was there before with this new list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way how to do this in a 2-step way:

```
vertexIdListPartition.update(3, 
  vertexIdListPartition.getOrElse(3, List()) ++ List(4,3)
```

I could not find a better way to do it in one step, which would be better though.

The `getOrElse` makes sure that if nothing is in there we return an empty list, otherwise we get the list that is already in there.  Afterwards we append your new list to it.